# Como hacer que una imagen svg no sea seleccionable por el usuario?

Tags: html, css, svg

Buen dia amigos, tengo un problema, resulta que utilice una imagen svg para agregar un degradado a mi sitio web pero precisamente encima de esa imagen svg hay un texto y digamos si quisiera seleccionar el texto, la imagen svg no lo permite pues al hacer la seleccion tambien me reconoce la imagen svg. Ya he intentado agregando a la imagen svg con CSS las propiedades user-select:none y cambiando los z-index, pero sigue pasando lo mismo.

Comparto una imagen para que me entiendan mejor, el cuadro blanco es el borde de la imagen svg, lo hice para hacerla resaltar y que se fijen hasta donde llega la seleccion del texto. Lo que quiero es hacer como si no estuviera hay la imagen svg. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y si pones la imagen como fondo?

Comment: Es que de hecho tengo 4 degradados a lo largo del sitio web. La foto de ejemplo es el cuarto section.

Answer (score 1):

Sencillo, era con la propiedad

**pointer-events: none**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events